# Node.js Login using http post and get data after log in

Tags: node.js, http, sails.js

How to do following actions using Node.js http POST, GET?

- Log in to abc.com(It is a login page with login form)
- In the page after log in, fill another form using POST and GET the result after posting the form.

Comment: Visit http://passportjs.org/

Answer (score 1):

Use the request module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request. Inspect the login form, look at it's `method` and `action`, the using request send a request of the method type to the action with the needed form data.  Then use the response's origin to see what the route of the next page is, and then POST to that route.  You shouldn't need the GET then, it should respond with the result.

But instead of all this, if the site has supports oauth, you'd be much better off authenticating doing that with passport.js and using their api.